# Laravel 4 - two submit buttons in one form and have both submits to be handled by different actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a login form which has email and password fields. And I have two submit buttons, one for login ( if user is already registered ) and the other one for registration ( for new users ). As the login action and register action are different so I need some way to redirect the request with all the post data to its respective action. Is there a way to achieve this in Laravel 4 in pure Laravel way?

Comment: Give the submit buttons different names.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The way I would do it

If your form is (2 buttons):

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'test/auth')) }}
{{ Form::email('email') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
{{ Form::password('confirm_password') }}
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Create a controller 'TestController'

Add a route

```
Route::post('test/auth', array('uses' => 'TestController@postAuth'));
```

In **TestController** you'd have one method that checks which submit was clicked on and two other methods for login and register

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function postAuth()
    {
        //check which submit was clicked on
        if(Input::get('login')) {
            $this->postLogin(); //if login then use this method
        } elseif(Input::get('register')) {
            $this->postRegister(); //if register then use this method
        }

    }    

    public function postLogin()
    {
        echo "We're logging in";
        //process your input here Input:get('email') etc.
    }

    public function postRegister()
    {
        echo "We're registering";
        //process your input here Input:get('email') etc.
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ClickCoder, you are right. But any idea, how to pass input data to Laravel's restful store() action without disrupting the functionality ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you already have postLogin and postRegister (or similar methods) and you simply want to route to either login or register.

`Route::post('test/auth', function() {
 if(Input::get('login')) {
  $action = 'postLogin';
 } elseif(Input::get('register')) {
  $action = 'postRegister';
 }
 return App::make('TestController')->$action();
});`

does that help? You'll have all the input in whichever controllers you use.

Comment: Yes, you understood it right. That is exactly what I want. I will try the code you gave and let you know the result. Though just by looking at the code I can tell this is going to work perfect. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks again, the code in the comment worked wonderfully. This is exactly what I needed. It seems to be a much more cleaner way to achieve the desired result. YOU ARE AWESOME :-)

Comment: The method what I searched for long-long time. Please take my upvote, sir.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

first I set up form with no action

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = "{{ URL::to('/'); }}";   
</script>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => '', 'id'=> 'test-form')) }}
{{ Form::text('username') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
{{ Form::password('confirm_password') }}
<input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login">
<input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

for routes (routes.php):

```
Route::post('test/login', array('uses' => 'TestController@login'));
Route::post('test/register', array('uses' => 'TestController@register'));
```

controller (TestController.php)

```
public function login(){
    //do something...
}

public function register(){
    //do something...
}
```

Jquery: (test.js)

```
$('form :submit').on('click', function(event){

    var a = $(this);
    var form = $('form');
    var action = a.attr('id');

    form.attr('action', baseUrl + '/test/' + action);
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: you save my lots of time!

Answer (score 3):

ClickCoder's answer is spot-on, the only thing I would replace, to do it in an 100% "pure Laravel way" would be to use the Form Builder for the submit buttons as well.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#buttons

The first parameter is the submit's value, and you can pass its name in the following options array.

So instead of:

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
```

You'd do:

```
{{ Form::submit('Login', ['name' => 'login']) }}
{{ Form::submit('Register', ['name' => 'register']) }}
```

If you'd like, you could escape the if statement altogether by having them share the same name and do something like this:

html:

```
{{ Form::submit('Login', ['name' => 'action']) }}
{{ Form::submit('Register', ['name' => 'action']) }}
```

php:

```
public function postAuth()
{
    $action = 'post' . Input::get('action'); //becomes either postLogin or postRegister
    $this->$action();
}
```

A bit less nesting, a bit more Laravel!

Comment: Cool suggestion, but this doesn't work so well if the value of the submit button is more than one word

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following:

**Your routes (routes.php):**

```
Route::post('post1', array('before' => 'checkForm', 'uses' => 'TestController@post1'));

Route::get('post2', array('as' => 'post2', 'uses' => 'TestController@post2'));
```

**filters.php**

```
Route::filter('checkForm', function()
{
    if(Input::has('button2')) {
        return Redirect::route('post2')->withInput();
    } 
});
```

**TestController.php**

```
public function post1(){
        return Input::all();
    }

    public function post2(){
        return Input::old();
    }
```

**Form:** should be in your view.however, I have created a temp form in route file for this answer.

```
Route::get('form2', function() 
{
      return Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('post1'))).
             Form::text('name', null).
             Form::email('email', null).
             '<button type="submit" name="button1" value="1">submit</button>'.
             '<button type="submit" name="button2" value="2">submit2</button>'.
           Form::close();

});
```

now browse:

```
http://yourDomain/form2
```

**Please note:** I am not sure this is the right approach to allow two submit buttons but it work for two submit buttons.

Comment: Thanks Anam for explaining in such a detail. Just wanted to know, is there a way to redirect to an action with all the input ?

Comment: you can redirect with `withInput();`. After redirect, you can get all inputs by using `Input::old();`. check my answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

Give the submit buttons different names, eg

```
<button type="submit" name="login">Login</button> 
<button type="submit" name="signup">Signup</button>
```

In your controller, simply handle login or signup depending on which button was submitted. You will still get all your inputs, you can do this;

```
public function postLoginOrSignup(){

    $data = Input::all();

    if(isset($data['login'])){
        //handle login process
    }

    if(isset($data['signup'])){
        //handle singup process
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This works great but the actual problem starts from here. Now desired action can be called but then I will have to pass the input data as a parameter to the action. Then I have to modify the way my restful action works. Which I don't want. I want to let Laravel restful store() action intact. Any idea ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I do not really understand the comment, can you please elaborate with some examples of what you do not want and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Simply put, is there a way to pass on the Input to the respective action ?