# multiple submit buttons in one form correlating to javascript functions please

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a php form which requires two submit buttons. One to submit the form using ajax(which works), but now i need to add another button which will complete the sale.

My current approach is adding another submit button to form & trying to distinguish between the two in javascript (which i dont know how to do).

so any help here would be appreciated or any othher recommended approach please.

php form

```
<form id="bidForm">
    <div class="form-group" id="divCheckbox" style="visibility: hidden">
        {{ Form::hidden('item_id', $item->id) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::User()->id) }}
    </div>
    <!-- bid    -->
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 100px" style="text-align: right">
        {{Form::label('bid_amount', 'Bid:') }}
        {{Form::text('bid_amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>     'bid-amount']) }}
    </div>
    <!-- max bid   
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('max_bid', 'Max Bid:') }}
        {{Form::text('max_bid', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div> -->
    {{ Form::hidden('permission', "userr") }}

     <!-- submit``    -->
    <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::submit('Bid', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'submit']) }} 
    </div>
     {{ Form::close() }}
```

script

```
$( "#bidForm" ).submit(function( e ) {
// Async submit a form's input.
     e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var method = 'POST';
    var url= "/items/" + {{ $item->id }}; 
    //var bid = $("#winner").innerHTML().val();
    var bid = document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML;
    var new_bid = $("#bid-amount").val(); 
         bigger = (new_bid > bid) ? true : false;
         console.log('');
    if(bigger){
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(),
            action:"http://localhost:8000/items" + {{ $item->id }},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("AJAX request was successfull");
                $('#bid-amount').val('');
            },
            failure: function() {
                console.log("AJAX request failed");
            }

        });
    }
    else{
        window.alert("This is not a high bid");

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation of ClickCoder's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932543/laravel-4-two-submit-buttom-in-one-form-and-have-both-submits-to-be-handled-by) is would solve your problem.

EDIT:

Ok so you could do the following with your submit buttons:

```
{{Form::submit('Bid', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary submit', 'id' => 'bid']) }}

{{Form::submit('Complete Sale', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary submit', 'id' => 'sale']) }}
```

and then distinguish between them in JS like so:

```
$('.submit').on('click', function(e){
//When a submit is clicked
e.preventDefault();
//prevent submit button default action
var $token = $(this).attr('id');
//get the id of the submit
if($token == 'bid'){
//If the clicked submit has an id of bid - Do Ajax stuff
}else{
//Do sale stuff
}
});
```

Comment: hi, as i was saying i need a JavaScript implementation as i am using ajax. although a php implementation would technically work, the knock on effect would be the page reloading so this would not be acceptable.

Comment: Edited answer above with a simple implementation for distinguishing between which button was clicked.

Comment: this almost works. it returns the id of the form, not the button. thanks for your help so far

Comment: I just altered it to correct an error I made. Add a class of submit to each button and then put a dot before submit in your jquery target like above. Also altered the variable to $this instead of this. I'm only on my first cup of coffee so i'm not at the races yet!