# Laravel One Form Two Submit Buttons

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have my form view;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET" action="">

@foreach($input as $key => $value)
    @foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue)                            
        {!! Form::hidden($key.'_'.$subkey, $subvalue) !!}
    @endforeach
@endforeach

{!! Form::hidden('postcode_id', $postcode_lookup['id']) !!}

<input class="btn btn-info"    type="submit" name="action" value="Map View"     />
<input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="action" value="CSV Download" />

</form>
```

I have my Routes.php code;

```
if ( Input::get('action') === 'CSV Download' )
{
  Route::get('/export/csv', 'ExcelController@index');
}

if ( Input::get('action') === 'Map View' )
{
  Route::get('/map/all', 'MapController@index');
}
```

If the user clicks one button, I want them the ExcelController called. If it's the other, I want MapController called... Two different Controllers!

What should my `action` route be? At the moment it just stays on the current page when I click either.

Comment: You should give your buttons different names

Comment: @blackbishop I refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547821/two-submit-buttons-in-one-form

Comment: You could also see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932543/laravel-4-two-submit-buttom-in-one-form-and-have-both-submits-to-be-handled-by)

Comment: touché - This is not quite what I am after as I have two separate controllers. Otherwise I would probably use that

Answer (score 2):

The action route is empty, so directs to the current page. It should be to some route. For example

```
<.. action="{{ URL::to('split_form') }}" ..>
```

You could then attach a filter to your route (in routes.php):

```
Route::get('split_form', array('before' => 'form_splitter'));
```

And define this filter (in filters.php)

```
Route::filter('form_splitter', function()
{
    if ( Input::get('action') === 'CSV Download' )
    {
        Redirect::to('/export/csv');
    }
    elseif ( Input::get('action') === 'Map View' )
    {
       Redirect::to('/map/all');
    }
});
```

And define the actual routes (in routes.php)

```
Route::get('/export/csv', 'ExcelController@index');
Route::get('/map/all', 'MapController@index');
```

Though the answer by angelo in blackbischop's second link could also work for what you want, saving you a filter/redirect by using javascript

Comment: I'm getting a Function does not exist error. Do I have to register the filters.php file I have just created somehow?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same name and different value attribute for the submit buttons

//  example:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save and close" name="submitbutton">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="apply" name="submitbutton">
```

//  Controller:

```
switch($request->submitbutton) {

    case 'save and close': 
        //action save here and close
    break;

    case 'apply': 
        //action for save and route here
    break;
}
```

or

```
    if ($request->submitbutton == 'apply') {
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.edit', $product->id)->with('success', "new product {$product->name} created as well.");
    } else if ($request->submitbutton == 'save and close'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index')->with('info', "product {$product->name} saved");
    }
```

my full answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087033/308578