# Laravel form with two submit button

Tags: php, laravel

I need two submit button for my update form,

#### current setting

Currently when I hit submit it saves my data and redirect me another page where i can edit my multiple images (so my form is like two step function)

#### What I want to add

I want to add another button in order to just save my data and return me to index page (skip second step)

#### last result

Last result will be my edit form with two button

1. button 1 saves data and return me to next form to edit my images
2. button 2 saves data and return me to index page

## Codes

`controller function`

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      // validation and....

      $product->save();

      // this is my current button action (redirect to second step)
      return redirect()->route('editmultiimages',
          $product->id)->with('success',
          'Product, '. $product->title.' updated, now you can edit images.');

     // need second button action here
}
```

`blade form`

```
{{ Form::model($product, array('route' => array('products.update', $product->id), 'method' => 'PUT', 'files' => true)) }}

// my inputs

// my current button (saves data and goes to next step)
{{ Form::submit('Edit Images', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}

{{Form::close()}}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SOLVED

`blade form`

```
{{ Form::submit('Edit Images', array('class' => 'btn btn-info', 'name' => 'submitbutton')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Finish', array('class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'submitbutton')) }}
```

`controller`

```
switch ($request->submitbutton) {
        case 'Edit Images':
            return redirect()->route('editmultiimages', $product->id)->with('success', 'Product, '. $product->title.' updated, now you can edit images.');
            break;

        case 'Finish':
            Session::flash('success', 'Product, '. $product->title.' updated successfully.');
            return redirect()->route('products.index', $product->id);
            break;
}
```

Hope it help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two submit buttons with different value attributes.

**View :**

```
...

{{ Form::submit('Edit Images', array('class' => 'btn btn-success','name'=>'btnSubmit', 'value'=>'button1')) }}

{{ Form::submit('Edit Images', array('class' => 'btn btn-success','name'=>'btnSubmit', 'value'=>'button2')) }}

...
```

**Controller :**

```
public function update(Request request) {

  if(request->get('btnSubmit') == 'button1') {

    // do your stuff here...

  } else if(request->get('btnSubmit') == 'button2') {

    // do your stuff here...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same name and different value attribute for the submit buttons

//  example:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save and close" name="submitbutton">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="apply" name="submitbutton">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save and new" name="submitbutton">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save and search" name="submitbutton">
```

//  Controller:

```
switch($request->submitbutton) {

    case 'save and close': 
        //action save here and close
    break;

    case 'save and new': 
        //action for save and new
    break;

    case 'save and search': 
        //action for save and search
    break;

    case 'apply': 
        //action for save and route here
    break;
}
```

or

```
    if ($request->submitbutton == 'apply') {
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.edit', $product->id)->with('success', "new product {$product->name} created as well.");
    } else if ($request->submitbutton == 'save and search'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index', ['name' => $product->name])->with('success', "product {$product->name} saved.");
    } else if ($request->submitbutton == 'save and close'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.index')->with('info', "product {$product->name} saved");
    } else if ($request->submitbutton == 'save and new'){
        return redirect()->route('admin.products.create' , $request->category_id)->with('info', "product {$product->name} saved.");
    }
```